# How can I improve my training phase with transformers? (text classification)

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I'm new to stackOverflow, I'm working on improving loss and accuracy on a bert base italian model (for istance, neuraly/bert-base-italian-cased-sentiment on huggingface) with a different dataset through fine tuning.
So I'd want to ask some questions and show some of the code to let you better understand.
So this is the code for the training phase:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
model.to(device)
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters())
trainset = TokenizerLoader(t_df0.reset_index())
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=3, shuffle=True)
for epoch in range(6):
      model.train()
      total_loss = 0
      steps = 0
      print( f"epoch n. {epoch}")
      for batch in trainloader:
        steps += 1
        labels = torch.zeros((batch[2].shape[0],3),device=device)
        for i,x in zip(range(batch[2].shape[0]),batch[2]):
          labels[i][int(x)]=1
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        m = model(input_ids=batch[0].to(device), attention_mask=batch[1].to(device),labels=labels)
        loss = m.loss
        total_loss += loss
        if steps%15 == 0:
          print('True labels: ',batch[2].view(1,-1), 'Predicted labels: ', torch.argmax(m.logits,axis=1))
          print('AVG Loss: ', total_loss/steps)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I tried to test the model before tuning it on a different part of the dataset and after tuning it, the accuracy gets worse after the fine tuning.
I read on huggingface that the loss criterion on a bert transformer is by default a Cross entropy loss.
When I start this phase the loss starts to slowly but steadily go down, but every 15 steps when I print a comparison between true and pred labels I found that it really gets a worse accuracy on the training set, so it does after on the test set.
I'm new to the field of text classification and I'd want some tips to improve this, feel free to ask me other code or to explain how is built the dataset, tokenizer, etc...
It really feels different with respect to computer vision and images related-ML

Thanks

Comment: Which data set are you using for the fine tuning?

Comment: @SilentCloud We made it, it's built on amazon reviews in italian language, we downloaded specific reviews with a Chrome extension, and then we formatted them in two columns, text and score

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask this kind of question.